# Are there Countable $\omega$- models of ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, nonstandard-models

By the [$\text{L-S}_\downarrow$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) theorem we know that there must exist a countable model of ZFC. Suppose that there is an $\omega$ model of ZFC, then would [$\text{ L-S}_\downarrow$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem) theorem entail that there must exist an $\omega$ model of ZFC that is countable? Or all countable models of ZFC must have non standard naturals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, by the LS theorem, we know that *if there is any model of ZFC* then there is a countable model. In fact, it says there is a countable elementary submodel of the original model. By the same token, if there is a *well-founded* model of ZFC then LS implies it has a countable elementary submodel, which is necessarily well-founded since it is a submodel of a well-founded model. And well-founded models are $\omega$-models: the Mostowski collapse gives the relevant isomorphism.

Note however that the existence of a well-founded model is a stronger assumption than the existence of a model (but it's not *that* much stronger an assumption, nowhere near the strength of inaccessible cardinals). Actually, the usual argument for this ties to your question. The minimal transitive model of ZFC is $L_\alpha$ for the smallest $\alpha$ that is the height of a transitive model. In light of the discussion above, it's easy to see that it is a countable $\omega$-model of ZFC. According to this model, there are no transitive / well-founded models of ZFC for reasons you might suspect, however since it is an $\omega$-model, it agrees with the universe about arithmetic, and hence that Con(ZFC) holds, and hence that there are models of ZFC.

Comment: Elaborating on the last paragraph, note that there is also a huge difference between $\omega$-models and transitive models. For example, there are $\omega$-models which are low for hyperjump, whereas any transitive model has to compute basically every real you can imagine.